# How to load paragraph entity on node object?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I'm using paragraphs in my content type. I've created a paragraph type and added content. Now I want to load the paragraphs in a `foreach`. But nothing's showing up. `$paras` is empty:

```
$node  = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(1);
$paras = $node->get('field_paragraph')->referencedEntities();
```

Comment: You said _$paras showing blank._ but you didn't show how you printed its value. Is it a `NULL` value, an empty string, or an empty array? Since you commented with _I already done this but your answer is right_ to the answer, which is showing completely different code, your question gets a little confused, and it's not clear what your aren't able to achieve.

Comment: This question asked when I am very new in drupal 8 doing task for learning .I think I do some error in process so that time it show blank .But when i do same now it's working fine. you check here a demo run same code . I just create this for you ,https://d2log.ply.st/devel/php 
username :: admin
password :: admin

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$paragraph = $node->field_paragraph->getValue();
// Loop through the result set.
foreach ( $paragraph as $element ) {
  $p = \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::load( $element['target_id'] );
  $text = $p->field_name->getValue();
}
```

Comment: I already done this but your answer is right.

Comment: Be careful: this solution doesn't include translations.

Comment: Instead of Paragraph::load($tid), we now should use \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('paragraph')->load($tid).

Comment: Don't load paragraphs by target_id, they are referenced by revision. The code in the question and the other answer using referencedEntities() is correct. See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/entity_reference_revisions/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/EntityReferenceRevisionsFieldItemList.php

Answer (score 20):

Just replace `get()` with field name directly :

```
$node  = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(1);
$paras = $node->field_paragraph->referencedEntities();
```

Comment: Wow, yes, but why?

Answer (score 4):

This method will work a bit faster.

```
// Get data from field.
if ($paragraph_field_items = $node->get('field_paragraph')->getValue()) {
  // Get storage. It very useful for loading a small number of objects.
  $paragraph_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph');
  // Collect paragraph field's ids.
  $ids = array_column($paragraph_field_items, 'target_id');
  // Load all paragraph objects.
  $paragraphs_objects = $paragraph_storage->loadMultiple($ids);
  /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
  foreach ($paragraphs_objects as $paragraph) {
    // Get field from the paragraph.
    $text = $paragraph->get('field_title')->value;
    // Do something with $text...
  }
}
```

You can also easily implement this code in some method in your custom service with `@entity_type.manager` argument and load storage for nodes and paragraphs in `__construct()`.

Comment: There's no need for all this code, you can get all paragraphs by one line:

`$node->field_my_paragraphs->referencedEntities();`