# Retrieving value of paragraph type with entity reference revision through preprocessor

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have created a paragraph type which has field of type entity reference, link, plain text.

Now I want to fetch the values present in these through the preprocessor.paragraph.inc and display it in the custom template(twig).

Can anyone please let me know how do i do this?

I have written a hook function in the preprocessor, but unable to fetch values of paragraph types.

Eg of my paragraphs type:

1. Section
2. Box

In the section contains 2 fields,
  first is the title which is a plain text and 
second is the box, which is an entity reference revision

The box, is a paragraph type which has many fields like

1. Link
2. Image
3. text field
4. Wysiwig

Now how do i access values present in these through the hook function and display the same in twig template.

Comment: What Drupal version is this? Twig sound like D8, but preprocessor.paragraph.inc sounds like D7.

Comment: Drupal 8 version

Comment: And what's this `preprocessor.paragraph.inc`?

Comment: We are creating hooks in this preprocessor.paragraph.inc

Comment: And include that into your `.theme` or `.module` file?

Comment: Display what values exactly in what template exactly?

Comment: Yes, we would include that . Currently I am able to fetch the value of title, which is a plain text within the section paragraph type. Now I need to fetch the values present in the BOX(paragraph type) Section has a field which is an entity reference revision which includes box.

Comment: $variables['content']['field_module_title'] : through this i was able to fetch the title, when i try the same with the column, which is the container for the box, it doesnt support,

Answer (score 0):

Every paragraph can be preprocessed with `template_preprocess_paragraph` or even more specific with `template_preprocess_paragraph__PARAGRAPH_TYPE`.

Check this sample below, where I get the value of `field_foobar` of the paragraph type `box` and pass it to the Twig template. It's a little bit redundant as this value can be accessed from the template itself, but you wanted to know how to pass values from a preprocess function to Twig. Here's how:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {

  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];

  if ($paragraph->getType() === 'box') {
    if (!$paragraph->field_foobar->isEmpty()) {

      $variables['foobar'] = $paragraph->get('field_foobar')->first()->getValue();
    }
  }
}
```

And then in `paragaph.html.twig`:

```
{% if foobar %}
  <div class="foobar">{{ foobar }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

---

Same principle applies for other preprocess functions and templates. On node level, on page level, even in fields or views. See [How to load paragraph entity on node object?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/238880/15055) It's just that you need to get hold of the entity ID your paragraph field is referencing, load the paragraph from that ID and then you get every field you want. For example inside `template_preprocess_html`:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    if ($node->bundle() === 'article') {

      $my_paragraphs = $node->get('field_paragraphs')->getValue();

      foreach ($my_paragraphs as $item) {

        $paragraph = \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::load($item['target_id']);

        if ($paragraph->getType() === 'box') {
          if (!$paragraph->field_foobar->isEmpty()) {

            $variables['foobar'] = $paragraph->get('field_foobar')->first()->getValue();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can access `{{ foobar }}` in `html.html.twig`.

---

You may want to install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)'s submodule Kint. Then you can dump all variables in templates with `{{ kint() }}` or in PHP with `ksm($variables)`. Then check the dump for what values or methods you get and then use them in your code.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the way one of the hook is working,

Comment: I see that $section_column['entity_info']['bundle']['#markup']; this actually shows up the paragraph which is linked to the parent paragraph.
In my case i do not have 'entity_info' in my json structure.