# Displaying parent field value in field.html.twig template from nested paragraphs

Tags: hooks, paragraphs

See attached please. Using [field.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21claro%21templates%21classy%21field%21field.html.twig/9) and [paragraph.html.twig](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/paragraphs/theming-paragraphs-in-drupal-8), Paragraphs 8.x-1.16 Stable release and Drupal 9.5.10

field.html.twig (specifically: field--paragraph--sidebar-button-repeater.html.twig):

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a field.
 *
 * To override output, copy the "field.html.twig" from the templates directory
 * to your theme's directory and customize it, just like customizing other
 * Drupal templates such as page.html.twig or node.html.twig.
 *
 * Instead of overriding the theming for all fields, you can also just override
 * theming for a subset of fields using
 * @link themeable Theme hook suggestions. @endlink For example,
 * here are some theme hook suggestions that can be used for a field_foo field
 * on an article node type:
 * - field--node--field-foo--article.html.twig
 * - field--node--field-foo.html.twig
 * - field--node--article.html.twig
 * - field--field-foo.html.twig
 * - field--text-with-summary.html.twig
 * - field.html.twig
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 * - label_hidden: Whether to show the field label or not.
 * - title_attributes: HTML attributes for the title.
 * - label: The label for the field.
 * - multiple: TRUE if a field can contain multiple items.
 * - items: List of all the field items. Each item contains:
 *   - attributes: List of HTML attributes for each item.
 *   - content: The field item's content.
 * - entity_type: The entity type to which the field belongs.
 * - field_name: The name of the field.
 * - field_type: The type of the field.
 * - label_display: The display settings for the label.
 *
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_field()
 */
#}
{%
  set classes = [
    'field',
    'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
    'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
    'field--label-' ~ label_display,
  ]
%}
{%
  set title_classes = [
    'field__label',
    label_display == 'visually_hidden' ? 'visually-hidden',
  ]
%}
    <div style="background: [field_button_container_color]; ">
        {% for item in items %}
            {{ item.content }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

paragraph.html.twig

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a paragraph.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - paragraph: Full paragraph entity.
 *   Only method names starting with "get", "has", or "is" and a few common
 *   methods such as "id", "label", and "bundle" are available. For example:
 *   - paragraph.getCreatedTime() will return the paragraph creation timestamp.
 *   - paragraph.id(): The paragraph ID.
 *   - paragraph.bundle(): The type of the paragraph, for example, "image" or "text".
 *   - paragraph.getOwnerId(): The user ID of the paragraph author.
 *   See Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph for a full list of public properties
 *   and methods for the paragraph object.
 * - content: All paragraph items. Use {{ content }} to print them all,
 *   or print a subset such as {{ content.field_example }}. Use
 *   {{ content|without('field_example') }} to temporarily suppress the printing
 *   of a given child element.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 *   The attributes.class element may contain one or more of the following
 *   classes:
 *   - paragraphs: The current template type (also known as a "theming hook").
 *   - paragraphs--type-[type]: The current paragraphs type. For example, if the paragraph is an
 *     "Image" it would result in "paragraphs--type--image". Note that the machine
 *     name will often be in a short form of the human readable label.
 *   - paragraphs--view-mode--[view_mode]: The View Mode of the paragraph; for example, a
 *     preview would result in: "paragraphs--view-mode--preview", and
 *     default: "paragraphs--view-mode--default".
 * - view_mode: View mode; for example, "preview" or "full".
 * - logged_in: Flag for authenticated user status. Will be true when the
 *   current user is a logged-in member.
 * - is_admin: Flag for admin user status. Will be true when the current user
 *   is an administrator.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_paragraph()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
{%
  set classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished'
  ]
%}
{% block paragraph %} 
    {% block content %}  
     <div class="Buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
     </div>
   {% endblock %}
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

How do I get the field value `field_button_container_color` (see screenshot) from the outer paragraph type `sidebar_button_repeater` and display its value specifically in the template `field--paragraph--sidebar-button-repeater.html.twig` to set the background color of a div?

```
<div style="background: {{ bgcolor }} ">
*[content]*
<div>
```

See 3rd screenshot for goal output.

For prepreocess code purposes let's say my theme name is `mytheme`.

Hoping to use something like IgorAgatti suggested in comments below but can't get it to work

```
function mytheme_preprocess_sidebar_button_repeater(array &$variables) {
  $bgcolor = $variables['content']['field_button_container_color'];
}
```

and simply add `{{ bgcolor }}` to `field--paragraph--sidebar-button-repeater.html.twig`

I also tried:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {

  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];

  if ($paragraph->getType() === 'sidebar_button_repeater') {
    if (!$paragraph->field_button_container_color->isEmpty()) {

      $variables['bgcolor'] = $paragraph->get('field_button_container_color')->first()->getValue();
    }
  }
}
```

...with no success. (inspired by [Retrieving value of paragraph type with entity reference revision through preprocessor](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282195/retrieving-value-of-paragraph-type-with-entity-reference-revision-through-prepro))

I believe the issue may be specific to actually rendering the value in a **field** template.

Thanks

Paragraph Type Structure
[image]
[image]
Goal Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the paragraph preprocess to alter the array of field_paragraph_inner

so it would be something like (untested code)

```
funcion hook_preprocess_field_paragraph_outer(array &$variables) {
  $field_bg = $variables['content']['field_bg'];

  $variables['content']['field_paragraph_inner']['field_bg_copy'] = $field_bg;
}
```

And you could use it in the field_inner_paragraph twig by just referencing `{{ field_bg_copy }}`

Comment: I couldn't get your solution to work so I reworded the question to be make things clearer. Thanks.